# How can I identify what is blocking port 1433?

Tags: sql, azure, port

I like to consider myself a fairly smart individual with the superb ability to "Google" things. However, I am running into an issue that is driving me insane.

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft Azure SQL Server from my Alienware Laptop running Windows 10, over 5Ghz WiFi. It seems that something is blocking port 1433 (according to many Google results). Unfortunately, I have opened this port on my Nighthawk router, through Windows' Firewall (wf.msc) via inbound rule, and finally I have enabled port 1433 in Bitdefender for all applications. I still cannot connect to the SQL instance through SSMS (even tried DBeaver). I am getting TCP rejection messages "forcibly closed by remote host"

Here is the kicker. I can access my database on the same device through a vb.net application (though I believe this is a different port). The bottom line is, I know the credentials, I am the admin, but I cannot get port 1433 truly open.

What other steps can I try to remedy this situation? Any and all help will be appropriately credited.

Comment: It may be in use, please see this page in case it is relevant:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2016/10/05/tcp-port-is-already-in-use/

Comment: Try port 2433, see if any difference

Comment: I have tried opening port 2433 both inbound and outbound TCP and no change.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the port 1433 for **outbound traffic** from your local network instead of the inbound, also make sure you have added your **client public IP address** in your Azure SQL server firewall via the Azure Portal.

The full troubleshooting steps as below:

1. Ensure you have the appropriate ports open outbound from your local network or connection (typically port 1433)
2. [Create a server-level firewall rule for your SQL database using the Azure portal.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal-firewall)
3. Ensure you are using the correct server name and username for SSMS, the server name should be something like this: mynewserver20170313.**database.windows.net**.
4. Ensure you are using SQL Server Authentication
   For SSMS the username format is username@servername

Ref: [Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect and query data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms)

Comment: Thank you, but these are all things I previously tried on Google, as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Could you use [telnet](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/telnet/) domain name port 1433 to verify the connectivity on your Laptop? If turn off temporarily all the firewalls and uninstall anti-virus software, telnet again. Are the two telnet results the same? Not sure you open the port 1433 outbound traffic. It should be the direction from your local environment to Azure SQL Server.